# Grabbing String Contents Python

Tags: python, string

Currently I'm creating a stock trading programing in Python that allows users to buy and sell stocks. Simple enough.

[image]

What I'm having trouble doing is I want to grab the price of this stock. WHich in this case is 19.03. So I'm wondering if there is a way to read a string starting from the nth character.

So for example: I want to grab the text from character 41 to character 48 in this string and assign it to a variable. How would I do that in Python?

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something - don't you just want `text[41:48]`?    Or maybe `text[41:49]`, if you want to include character 48.

Comment: You should probably tackle a smaller project first.

Comment: Hi Paul, you may need to find out some regex, i believe slicing may not be your good solution as the starting index of the slice is not certain for every line right ?

Comment: @Zirak, thank you for that suggestion, but just because I don't know certain things. Doesn't mean I'm a complete noob to the whole python language. I already have most of the program complete. Happydave Thank you.

Comment: So will you always need the range between the 41st and 48th character? Will the company name never vary in length? Or if you're only looking to do this for a single row, why not just copy the price value directly?

Comment: @Yopy I'm able to strip Spaces from the string, so now matter which stock it is 41 - 48 will include the price, some will include spaces.

Comment: @Asad, theres hundreds of stocks. But the way I have it setup is so that its spaced far enough away from the company name field so I can just strip the spaces.

Comment: Ok if you are certained about the start and end index, than i belive slicing would be your good options.

Comment: @PaulAlexanderBurkart You're missing my point. If the company name is, for example, 48 characters long, there is no way in the world `text[41:48]` will work, regardless of how many spaces you have in there.

Comment: @Asad I've already looked through my list, no company name is that long, not the ones I have. I made sure of that before posting. ANd if in the event I add one that long, I can also create a function that strips all letters from the price string

Comment: @Paul alexander Burkat,  What can suggest is try to make it generic as much as you can, don't always stick with the text you have right now, think about all the possible prabability.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your company name is not longer than 48 characters. If any of your symbols, spaces, company names or even the number changes in size (for example, if you have more than 9 entries assuming the rows have consecutive #'s), your program is going to fail. Stripping all letters wouldn't work, cause you'd probably have to strip numbers as well, but then your price consists of numbers...now there's a problem.

Comment: As I've already said @MyxL If that were to happen, I'll simply add more spaces in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just grab character 41 to character 48.

```
# your string
line = '1 VNET ... 19.03 ...'
# pick out the price
price = line[40:48]
```

What you really want to do is use regular expressions (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to match a pattern with the incoming string.

There's also a udacity class on regular expressions (https://www.udacity.com/course/cs262).

Here's an example of using a regular expression to parse it.

```
import re
line = '1 VENT 19.03'
re.match(r'(?P<id>\d)\s+(?P<company>\w+)\s+(?P<price>[\.\d]+)', line).groupdict()
```

{'price': '19.03', 'company': 'VENT', 'id': '1'}

Answer (score 1):

> If that were to happen, I'll simply add more spaces in between.

From your comments it would appear that you have complete control over the input AND the output (input being, the format of the row). In that case, you are creating a problem, and trying to solve the problem you've created. So, why not make it an easier problem to solve?

Instead of adding spaces, use tabs to separate each field. Then you can split your line on tabs and retrieve the price since it is always the 4th "column" in your entry.